# Angular radio button doesn't pick an initial value

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a radio button with two available values - male and female when the value of male is true and female is false.

```
<div id="gender" class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="userDetails.gender" btn-radio="true" uncheckable>Male</label>
    <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="userDetails.gender" btn-radio="false"
           uncheckable>Female</label>
</div>
```

In the controller code, I get the existing value in the server and then put it in the ng-model as follows:

```
 $scope.userDetails.gender = currentUser.get('Gender');
```

which returns true or false.

What I want is that the relevant radio button will be picked by the initial value, for example: if the controller code returns "true" I want the true button to be marked pressed.

Comment: What is `currentUser.get('Gender')` and what it returns? What is `console.log( typeof currentUser.get('Gender') )`.

Comment: It returns a true or false value that indicate if a user is male or female (true=male, false=female)

Comment: Check if the radio button group is indeed affected by that controller. For example place a `<span>{{userDetails.gender}}</span>` near the radio button group and see what is the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if the controller code returns "true" ...

I guess this is your problem. Your HTML configuration specifies that model value should have boolean type, not a *string*. So you need to make sure `currentUser.get('Gender')` returns `true/false` as boolean. Or otherwise define radio attributes as `btn-radio="'true'"` and `btn-radio="'false'"`

Comment: This was my exact thought too. I just had an issue with this in one of my projects.

Comment: Yes, that worked, I was sure i'm missing something else, thank you.